# How do I solve this python question? It is about copying the contents of one file to another file

Tags: python

**Below is the question I have.**

“Roma” is a leading manufacturer of footwear in the City. The Company ships their products to various dealers across the world through Gaaty Shipments, the trusted brand in the logistics industry. It is customary for the footwear Company to prepare a list of their products to be shipped for that week, in a text file and send a copy of it across to Gaaty Shipments.

In connection with this, the footwear company’s Manager intended to create a copy of this text file which contains all the product details to be shipped as
"Product - Product ID".
Help him by writing a program to copy the content from one file to another file.

For example, if the content of file_in.txt is

Aerosol - 38

Churn - 50

Plank - 55

Slipsheet - 75

Jerrican - 950

Girder - 100

the same should be copied to file_out.txt.

Input and Output Format :
Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.

Sample Input :
No Input.
Read the content from file (file name) : file_in.txt.  The file is already been available in the platform

Sample Output :
In output file, the content will be copied.
Write the content to the output file (file name) : file_out.txt and display it.

Example:

Aerosol - 38

Churn - 50

Plank - 55

Slipsheet - 75

Jerrican - 950

Girder - 100

**Below is the code I have**

```py
import shutil

a=open("file_out.txt","x")

shutil.copyfile("file_in.txt", "file_out.txt")
```

I can't figure out what I did wrong or maybe I misunderstood the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Comment: _I can't figure out what I did wrong_ Why do you think you did something wrong?  If your results are not what you wanted, explain what the code did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open the file. Just do

```py
import shutil

shutil.copyfile("a.txt", "b.txt")
```

The `a.txt` should be in the same folder where your python code is, otherwise use absolute file paths.